# Android: Resource not found exception in deployed app

Tags: android, crash, android-resources

We are facing a large number of Resource Not Found Exception in our deployed app on the google play store, and this error occurs only in some phones, and we are not able to reproduce the error in any way.

Obviously the drawable exists, and no I'm not using an Integer in the setText methods(), this occurs in the setContentView method. Therefore a drawable in the activity XML.

Also please note, that the activity is being initiated by a dynamic module.

StackTrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7e070000
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

**EDIT:** Found out the error was causing in Android 6.0 and lower only, and definitely due to dynamic module.

Comment: this missing resource may belong to any implremented lib, including Android Jetpack. are you using app bundle?

Comment: Yes, I'm using app bundle, and from the crash logs and resource id cross verification I can see the drawable exists in my app not in any external library

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your resources had been removed from the [R8 resource shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code), therefore at runtime the App does not find them.

Check all your ProGuard rules files and if you enabled the strict mode for shrinking resources.

There are some R8 / Gradle options to properly set, e.g. in the case your code use the `getIdentifier` method.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using resource shrinking nor any progaurd rule for shrinking.